# how to increase the long press timeout on button pressed in android

Tags: android

I have to implement long key press functionality in my App and it has to popup the dialog after 4 secs but long press timeout set in android around 1 sec, is there any way to increase the timeout time ?

Please help me resolve this problem.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard long-press timeout seems to be only 0.5 seconds (at least, that’s the value on my HTC Desire). You can, of course, implement your own long-press handling, using your own custom timeout, you don’t have to use the system value.

See how this [DrawView](https://github.com/ldo/view_cache_demo_android/blob/master/src/DrawView.java) class installs a custom “LongClicker” object to run after the long-press interval unless it gets cancelled first; that code uses the standard long-press interval, but you can customize the code to use some other interval.